# What widget should after be called on?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm using `after` to create a delayed callback. I noticed though that many different objects have an `after` method, and it isn't clear if there's any difference between calling `after` on say a `tk.Frame` or a `tk.Button`.

I haven't seen a single guide mention if you can expect identical behavior regardless of what object `after` is called on. Looking at the implementation, it seems like it just delegates to `self.tk.call('after', ms, name)` in a common base class of widgets, but that alone doesn't mean that the behavior will be identical for all subclasses.

If I have multiple widgets on-hand when I need to call `after`, is there any reason to choose one over another, or can I expect identical behavior regardless?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm using after to create a delayed callback. I noticed though that many different objects have an after method, and it isn't clear if there's any difference between calling after on say a tk.Frame or a tk.Button.

No, there is no difference. You can call `after` using any widget you want and it will behave exactly the same.

> Looking at the implementation, it seems like it just delegates to self.tk.call('after', ms, name) in a common base class of widgets, but that alone doesn't mean that the behavior will be identical for all subclasses.

Actually, it does. The fact that you call it as a method on a widget is an artifact of the Tkinter implementation. In the underlying tcl/tk library it's just a function call that isn't tied to any widget.